# Ubuntu 17.10 laptop touchpad is too sensitive

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.10

I was having problems with touchpad sensitivity after installing Ubuntu 17.10. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 laptop and the touchpad is extremely sensitive after installation. For example, the mouse moves normally for a few seconds and then it jumps across the page with the slightest touch. Its difficult to click any small buttons such as the "x" to close applications. If I move a tiny bit, the mouse goes slow but randomly moves across the screen.

Comment: Do you still have the OEM-installed OS on your laptop? Does the touchpad work well there? Please test now, instead of telling me what you remember it was like, because it might be a hardware issue.

Comment: Yeah I tested it and the mouse works fine on Windows. I ran into sensitivity problems after installing Ubuntu. I also noticed that the mouse works fine after keeping Ubuntu on for a while. However, its still very sensitive when I turn it on.

Comment: does that mean it's fast in the login screen (asking because that happens to me too)? Also are you using Wayland (default) or X.org? If you are using Wayland try to change to X.org from the login screen then report any changes in mouse speed you may notice.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it. The mouse is fast on both Wayland and Xorg during login and on the desktop.

Comment: This might be the fix you need (it's coming to 18.04, not a tutorial): https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/02/02/ubuntu-desktop-update-2-february-2018/?utm_content=bufferf57b0&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer